# Error using JSF 2.1 with JSP 2.0: Unable to read TLD from JAR file

Tags: java, jsp, maven, jsf-2, taglib

I try to use JSF 2.1 within JSP 2.0.

When I add this `<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>`

I get the following error:

```
Unable to read TLD "META-INF/html_basic.tld" from JAR file
    "file:/home/fadhel/.m2/repository/javax/javaee-web-api/6.0/javaee-web-api-6.0.jar":
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6169:
    Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class: com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.HtmlBasicValidator.
```

Can someone tell what I can do to use JSF 2.1 and JSP 2.0 with Java 6?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that particular Maven library is provided only for Java compilation. You can't use it at runtime (even for unit tests.) If you are getting this running against a server, make sure the dependency is marked as `provided`.

If you wish to load the library you will have to depend on a real API. Since there tends to be more than one implementation of just about every Java EE API you will have to research and choose these yourself.

Look for blog posts [like this one](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/trouble_with_crippled_java_ee) to resolve your particular problem.