# The jsp does not show the images

Tags: jsp, struts2, image

I am trying to show an image in jsp, I am using the following code but it does not show the image, it just shows an image icon which indicates the link is broken.

When I put the file in the images folder it works but it does not find the file when its in logos folder.

the image is in this address Web pages \ images \ logos \ Tulips.jpg

and my code is as following

```
   <%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
   ....

   <img src="<s:url value="/images/logos/Tulips.jpg"/>"/>

   .....
```

People suggested me to use the following, I have added the following code and the dependancy but it shows the following error on the taglib line.

```
    Unable to read TLD "META-INF/c.tld" from JAR file javaee-web-api.6.0.jar : org.apache.jasper.JasperException :PWC6169: Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class:
org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.jstlCoreTLV
```

jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<img src="<c:url value="/images/logos/Tulips.jpg"/>"/>
```

pom

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
                <artifactId>taglibs-parent</artifactId>
                <version>3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
          </dependency>
```

Comment: Where is this jsp located ?

Comment: Can you try `"./images/logos/Tulips.jpg"` ?

Comment: ahahah Mukul you beat me on time :)

Comment: But that makes no sense; it *shouldn't* be a relative path: (a) it's not a relative path, and (b) relative paths can break very badly depending on how the specific JSP is being used.

Comment: Just for clarification, you said it works in the images folder but not in the logos folder? So `<img src="<s:url value="/images/Tulips.jpg"/>"/>` works but when you move Tulips.jpg to `/images/logos` then `<img src="<s:url value="/images/logos/Tulips.jpg"/>"/>` no longer works?

Comment: @DaveNewton whats your suggestion ?

Comment: @DanielMorgan I don't have one other than using <c:url> which should work fine. There's no reason moving it would make it break unless it's just not being deployed.

Comment: @DaveNewton, so Alexy's answer is correct right?

Comment: @DanielMorgan If it works, sure. No real reason s:url shouldn't work, though.

Comment: There is a problem with either name or access... since I'm assuming you created all folders the same way, and I doubt you decided to set permissions in such a way that nothing could be accessed under logos... Ah, delete the folder and recreate it. Also deploy the application and look at the deployment to see if the jsp is where you expect it. There is nothing wrong with the s:url tag (you can verify it is constructing what you expect in the html source). You can manually type in a url to the correct image location and you should get an image. It's going to be something simple.

Answer (score 4):

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<img src="<c:url value="/images/logos/Tulips.jpg"/>"/>
```

**UPDATE**
Also have a look at these links:
[Error using JSF 2.1 with JSP 2.0: Unable to read TLD from JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015433/error-using-jsf-2-1-with-jsp-2-0-unable-to-read-tld-from-jar-file)
[Unable to read TLD "META-INF/c.tld"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452403/unable-to-read-tld-meta-inf-c-tld)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this also ?

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%>
    <img src="<html:rewrite page='/images/logos/Tulips.jpg/'>"/>
```

Comment: it runs into following error PWC6031: Unterminated &lt;html:rewrite tag

Comment: again error it says according to TLD, tag html:rewrite must be empty but it is not.

Comment: @DanielMorgan You shouldn't even have that TLD available to you.

Comment: The edit is still an unterminated `<html:rewrite>` tag, and it's the **wrong version of Struts**. That there are upvotes on this is baffling.